# Command lists wrong

Tags: bash, for

I have a bash script that lists all files in a directory:

```
for file in foo/*; do
  echo ${file##*/}
done
```

It works fine if there are files in the directory, but if there are no files it lists files one directory up.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing in the `foo` directory, the variable `file` will get the literal value `foo/*`.  The substitution `${file##*/}` will yield the string `*`, and with `echo` that will output all names in the current directory.

To fix this in `bash`, the simplest option would be to set the `nullglob` shell option with `shopt -s nullglob`. This ensures that file name globbing doesn't expand to the pattern itself if there are no names matching the pattern.

From the `bash` manual:

> `nullglob`
>
> If set, `bash` allows patterns  which  match  no  files
>                         (see  Pathname  Expansion  above) to expand to a null
>                         string, rather than themselves.

Ps. I wish that the manual used "names" or possibly "filenames" rather than "files".